# INSERT COM DUAS TABELAS - PHP

Tags: php, query, join, sql-insert

Tenho a tabela **alunos** e a tabela **pagamentos**, estou fazendo um sistema de academia. Relacionei as duas tabelas colocando o id_alunos na tabela pagamentos como chave estrangeira.

Quero que quando cadastrar as informações de alunos e informações de pagamentos, apareça na tela os dados juntos dessas duas tabelas.

O cadastro das informações do aluno(tabela alunos) é efetuado com sucesso, mas os do pagamento(tabela pagamentos) não insere no banco nada...

Ja procurei tentar fazer com **msql_insert_id** e mysqli_insert_id mas fala que isso não existe, e muito menos o **last_insert_id** ...

**CREATE.PHP**

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'conexao.php';

$nome = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nome',FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$cpf = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cpf', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$rg = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'rg', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$nascimento = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nascimento', 
FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$sexo = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'sexo', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$fone = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'fone', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$endereco = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'endereco', 
FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$bairro = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'bairro', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$cep = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cep', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$estado = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'estado',FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$cidade = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cidade', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$situacao_aluno = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'situacao_aluno', 
FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$validade_plano = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'validade_plano', 
FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$planos = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'planos', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$vencimento = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'vencimento', 
FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$cpf_amigo = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cpf_amigo', 
FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$forma_pagamento = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'forma_pagamento', 
FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$data_matricula = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'data_matricula', 
FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$numero_documento = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'numero_documento', 
FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$data_documento = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'data_documento', 
FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$valor = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'valor', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);

$querySelect1 = $link->query("select email from alunos");
$array_emails = [];

while($emails = $querySelect1->fetch_assoc()):
$emails_existentes = $emails ['email'];
array_push($array_emails,$emails_existentes);
endwhile;

if(in_array($email,$array_emails)):
$_SESSION['msg'] = "<p class='center red-text'>".'Já existe um aluno com 
esse email'."</p>";
    header("Location:../");
else:
 $queryInsert1 = $link->query ("insert into alunos values(default,'$nome'
'$cpf','$rg','$nascimento','$sexo','$fone','$email','$endereco','$bairro', 
'$cep','$estado','$cidade')");

$queryInsert2 = $link->query("insert into pagamentos values(default, 
$situacao_aluno','$validade_plano','$planos','$vencimento',
'$cpf_amigo','$forma_pagamento','$data_matricula',
'$numero_documento','$data_documento','$valor')");


    $affected_rows = mysqli_affected_rows($link);

    if($affected_rows > 0):
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "<p class='center green-text'>".'Cadastro 
     efetuado com sucesso!'."</br>";
        header("Location:../cadastro.php");
    endif;
   endif;
  ?>
```

**Eu já não sei mais o que fazer ... Algúem entende disso ?**

Answer (score 1):

```
Usa a função mysql_insert_id();

depois do insert aluno, vc usa mysql_insert_id() e grava em outra variavel.
Exemplo:
$aluno_ID = mysql_insert_id();

E depois usa essa variavel no seu insert pagamento
```

Comment: Olá...já fiz isso, mas não dá certo ...
me trás esse erro : 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_insert_id() in C:\xampp\htdocs\horus\banco_de_dados\create.php:48 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\horus\banco_de_dados\create.php on line 48

Minha linha 48 :
     `$fk_alunos = mysql_insert_id();
      $queryInsert2 = $link->query("insert into pagamentos values('$fk_alunos', 
       default, '$situacao_aluno','$validade_plano',....`

Comment: Para melhor visualização :
https://pastebin.com/wE5KcQQJ

Comment: Eu faria diferente
$queryInsert1 =  "insert into alunos values(default,'$nome'
'$cpf','$rg','$nascimento','$sexo','$fone','$email','$endereco','$bairro', 
'$cep','$estado','$cidade')";

$confirma_query1 = mysql_query($queryInsert1, $link);

$id_do_Aluno_inserido_acima = mysql_insert_id();

$queryInsert2 = "insert into pagamentos values(".$id_do_Aluno_inserido_acima.", 
$situacao_aluno','$validade_plano','$planos','$vencimento',
'$cpf_amigo','$forma_pagamento','$data_matricula',
'$numero_documento','$data_documento','$valor')"

$confirma_query2 = mysql_query($queryInsert2, $link);

Comment: Trouxe este erro : 
`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query() in C:\xampp\htdocs\horus - Copia\banco_de_dados\create.php:49 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\horus - Copia\banco_de_dados\create.php on line 49` .
A linha 49 é a $queryInsert1